# I ran a .exe setup file for MS Office 07

Tags: microsoft-office

I right clicked the setup.exe for word 2007 and ran it by wine 1.2.3 after installation i clicked ok but where do i find my new office software, not in dash home, can't find by terminal, i just installed ubuntu 12.4 lts today so please explain and answer this please

Comment: Unless you absolutely need MS Office, I'd like to recommend KingSoft office as a "clone" or alternative. It's quite alike to MS Office and I've personally had success using it in a business context with limited compatibility issues. You can download it here: http://wps-community.org/download.html

Comment: I would recommend installing MS Office via PlayOnLinux. Here is a useful link: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/easily-install-microsoft-office-2007-linux/

Comment: ++1 for PlayOnLinux... I had been using Crossover Office, but I find that PlayOnLinux works best and it's free... (and easy to setup).

Answer (score 0):

It should appear when looking for "Word" or "Excel" on the `dash` if it still doesn't, then go to the dash and look for `Explore C unit` that will prompt the "Wine space" on your computer, then look for the executable files.

The MS Office executable files are usually located at `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\Office12\WinWord.exe` (within the C unit and changing "WinWord.exe" by the office application desired). If you have any other questions, please let us know.

Note: The "C folder" is usually located at `Home/.wine/dosdevices/c:`.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems installing Office 07 under Wine 1.2.3.  See [Wine App Database](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=4992).

I would recommend that you upgrade your Wine installation to a later release, and try installing Office again.

Installed properly, you should be able to run the Installed office by typing Microsoft Office in Dash.